# RSpec anonymous controller for concern

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, guard

I'm trying to test a Rails controller concern (though I'm not sure this fact is at all related to my issue) in RSpec, so I figured I'd use an anonymous controller. Here's my setup:

```
describe MyConcern do
  controller do
    include MyConcern

    def edit
      puts "Checkpoint!"
      @value = concern_method
      render text: "test edit method called"
    end
  end

  it "should call concern_method" do
    get :edit, id: 1
    assigns(:value).should eq "expected_value" # Set by concern_method
  end
end
```

Now here's the weird part. I test using Guard. When Guard detects a save of the spec file and runs this test, it passes and `Checkpoint!` is printed. Every time, completely deterministically. I can keep saving the file and it keeps passing. (If it helps, Guard uses Spring and runs RSpec.)

But when I run the test with an RSpec command, it fails. Weirdest of all, I would have expected a failure to occur because something weird happens with the anonymous controller setup and it can't find the route, but instead it's the `should` that fails the test. When I run RSpec manually in this way, `Checkpoint!` never prints, indicating that the anonymous controller action isn't getting called. But because I don't get a route error, *some* controller action must be getting called but I have no idea what, as I don't even have any other anonymous controllers with an `edit` function that could possibly conflict. I've tried restarting Spring—no luck.

Any thoughts on what I could be doing wrong?

---

**Edit:**

Here's more info. The format of my concern is this:

```
module MyConcern
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    puts "Included!"

    private

    def concern_method
      puts "Method is called!"
      "expected_value"
    end
  end
end
```

When the test fails (from me running RSpec explicitly with `bundle exec rspec`), I get a pretty typical failure message:

```
Failure/Error: assigns(:value).should eq "expected_value"

       expected: "expected_value"
            got: nil

       (compared using ==)
```

The top of my Guardfile is just `guard :rspec, cmd: 'bundle exec spring rspec --color'`, and this behavior is the same even when I remove `spring` from that command. I really have no idea how to debug this one.

Comment: Could you post the rspec command you use to run the command and the output?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see that you had commented. I edited my question with more details; let me know if it's helpful at all or if I can provide more information.

Comment: Hmm... so just to confirm what you're saying, does `bundle exec spring rspec --color` produce a failure or a success for the test?

Comment: A failure. The only way it passes is when Guard detects a file change on save and runs the test automatically. It's not a test ordering issue though as `bundle exec spring rspec` fails even when all other tests are turned off.

Comment: hmmm... odd, my first thoughts were about the test ordering. The first thing we need to do is figure out why the guard tests are passing, since we get a failure from the command line while running the same command. The only thing I can think is that there is something in your environment (by which I mean your shell, bash/zsh/whatever) that is messing with the test? (either directly as an alias to `rspec` or `spring` or indirectly as an environment variable that is read by your code `ENV['MY_VAR']`.) That's all I can think of other than scary code-voodoo which I hope isn't the case. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think that [`controller` receives an argument](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/3-0/docs/controller-specs/anonymous-controller) which will be used as a base class and if you don't pass one it will use the thing that you `describe`. So your test is fishy :)

Try:

```
controller(ApplicationController) do
    ...
end
```